# $f_n$ converges uniformly to f but $f^2_n$ fails to converge uniformly to $f^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider functional sequence $f_{n}$ which is differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$. Find an example of $f_n$ converging uniformly to f on $\left(a,b\right)$ such that $f^2_n$ fail to converge uniformly to $f^2$ on $\left(a,b\right)$.

I have difficulty with making such sequence. Could you please help? I know the theorem that in order to preserve uniform convergence two sequences must be bounded, so, I believe the example might be some unbounded functional sequence.

Comment: Right, you need something unbounded. If $f$ is given, what is a simple sequence converging uniformly to $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any unbounded $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and consider a sequence $f_n :(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f_n (\xi ) =f(\xi ) +n^{-1} .$
Then $$\lambda_n =\sup_{\xi\in (a,b )} |f_n (\xi ) -f(\xi )|\leqslant n^{-1} \to 0$$ hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly but $$\varepsilon_n =\sup_{\xi\in (a,b )} |(f_n (\xi ))^2 -(f(\xi ))^2|=\sup_{\xi\in (a,b )} |-2n^{-1} f(\xi ) +n^{-2}| =\infty$$ hence $(f_n )^2 \to (f)^2 $ not uniformly.